# `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...` when trying to `require`

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I feel like I'm doing something really dumb here but I don't have a second set of eyes handy.

```
describe('app.backend.src.server', () => {
  const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
  const mach = require('mach.js'); // <- this is giving the error

  it('should pass to make sure Im not crazy', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Failures: 
1) app.backend.src.server encountered a declaration exception
1.1) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

package.json

```
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-istanbul": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-jasmine": "^2.4.2",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-tap": "^0.1.3",
    "jshint": "^2.9.4",
    "mach.js": "^0.5.0",
    "proxyquire": "^1.7.11",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2"
  }
  ...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, updated with error.

Comment: What version of node are you using?  That looks like the spread operator:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might be using an incompatible version of nodeJS.  That error message seems to indicate that the module in question (mach) is using the spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Maybe try updating your node version to one that supports the spread operator.  Node 6+ is a good choice.  Here's a great reference that stays up to date for feature support:

http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_(...)_operator

Comment: Sweet...I thought I was on the latest LTS version...and then I checked...